# ZipArchive alternative for iOS?

Tags: ios, unzip

Looking for a ZipArchive alternative for iOS that allows me to see the progress of the unzipping of a large file. Looked at ZipKit and Objective-Zip, but neither seem to give me any form of progress of the unzipping process. Do I have to roll my own or is there something out there that I've missed?

Comment: DDMinizip does give you  callbacks whenever it starts a file in the zip

Comment: Anyone else think the state of C/C++/Obj-C zipping/rarring libraries is absolutely abysmal? It's been years and I have yet to find nice code anywhere. Zip libraries seem to be the most spaghetti-ridden monstrosities in the 3rd-party library world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And of course shortly after posting this I come across [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive) which does exactly what I need.